# Transposing a text file in bash

Tags: bash, sed, awk

i have a file with names as

```
Input1 file1:45764 | file1:878755 | file1: 899787 
Input2 file1: 45676 | file1:769678 | file1: 6454764
```

Now I wish to do it like

```
Input1 file1:45764
Input1 file1:878755
Input1 file1: 899787
Input2 file1: 45676
Input2 file1:769678
Input2 file1: 6454764
```

Any guess? I tried `sed "s/s/n/g"` and `sed "s/s+/n/g"` but no success?

Comment: Is there always space in between `fileX:` and the number?

Comment: Yes there is always space between fileX:

Comment: Why then you comment in my answer that "Thanks, it worked but in some cases it is like filex:4733764 some text so it printed like Input1 filex:46684356 Input1 : text . I dont need text.i just need Input1 filex:8336462"??

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
$ awk -F' [|] ' '{split($1,fld,/ /);print $1;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)print fld[1],$i}' file
Input1 file1:45764
Input1 file1:878755
Input1 file1: 899787
Input2 file1: 45676
Input2 file1:769678
Input2 file1: 6454764
```

or **idiomatically** you could do:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/[|]/,ORS $1)' file
Input1 file1:45764
Input1 file1:878755
Input1 file1: 899787
Input2 file1: 45676
Input2 file1:769678
Input2 file1: 6454764
```

Answer (score 2):

Just bash:

```
while read input line; do
    IFS="|" read -a words <<< "$line"
    printf "$input %s\n" "${words[@]}"
done << END
Input1 file1:45764 | file1:878755 | file1: 899787 
Input2 file1: 45676 | file1:769678 | file1: 6454764
END
```

```
Input1 file1:45764 
Input1  file1:878755 
Input1  file1: 899787
Input2 file1: 45676 
Input2  file1:769678 
Input2  file1: 6454764
```